# css - alternating section styling?

Tags: css

I would like to alternate between white-on-black and black-on-white, switching whenever an `<h3>` is encountered. Is this possible? For example, in the following code,

```
<h3>Heading one</h3>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<h3>Heading two</h3>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
<h3>Heading three</h3>
<p>The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>The sixth paragraph.</p>
<h3>Heading four</h3>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The eighth paragraph.</p>
<p>The ninth paragraph.</p>
```

Headings one and three, and paragraphs 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 would be black-on-white; the others would be white-on-black.

The actual page content is authored in Markdown, so I can't simply wrap half the sections in a `<div class="inverted">` (the contents of an HTML tag in Markdown are parsed as HTML, but I want them to be parsed as Markdown.) I know about `nth-of-type` but it affects only the headings themselves.

Comment: you'll probably have to use javascript/jquery

Answer (score 3):

The following is not the best solution.  However, if you know, for sure, that a heading can be followed by a certain maximum number of paragraphs, then this can work universally without using JS & jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/CG5fU/1/.

CSS:

```
h3:nth-of-type(2n), 
h3:nth-of-type(2n) + p, 
h3:nth-of-type(2n) + p + p, 
h3:nth-of-type(2n) + p + p + p, 
h3:nth-of-type(2n) + p + p + p + p,
h3:nth-of-type(2n) + p + p + p + p + p, 
h3:nth-of-type(2n) + p + p + p + p + p + p,
h3:nth-of-type(2n) + p + p + p + p + p + p + p {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

And, here's a jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/CG5fU/3/.

```
$("h3:nth-of-type(2n)")
    .nextUntil("h3")
    .andSelf()
    .css({"background-color": "#000", 
          "color": "#fff"});
```

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, as css is a markup and not a programming language, its not suitable to work with dynamic content.

if you know how many paragraphs and headings you are going to have, then you can hardcode the styling as follows:

css:

```
h3:nth-of-type(1) ,h3:nth-of-type(1) ~ p{
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
h3:nth-of-type(2) ,h3:nth-of-type(2) ~ p{
    background:white;
    color:black;
}
h3:nth-of-type(3) ,h3:nth-of-type(3) ~ p{
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
h3:nth-of-type(4) ,h3:nth-of-type(4) ~ p{
    background:white;
    color:black;
}
```

live example: <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/5rt9L/)**</kbd>

if however, you do not know how many headings/paragraphs you are going to have, you will have to resort to JavaScript.

OR, you can just go on writing the styles up to `nth-of-type(100)`, im pretty sure you wont have more than 100 headers in your text. but i highly discourage this, better use javascript.

**UPDATE**

alrighty, in order to 'fill' the ugly white spaces, there are many tricks:

 one would be to remove the margins of the headers and paragraphs, but increase the line-height to create artificial line spaces:

```
p,h3{
    line-height:2em;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

another trick would be to use css3 pseudo selector `:after` to create a huge block of black/white background under the text to hide the spaces xD but this is rather heavy and complicated.

i have updated the first trick in the fiddle demo.

**UPDATE 2**

here is an example how to utilize `:after` selector to hide ugly background:
<kbd>**[:after Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/jA9cU/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hey, that's a neat trick! But I guess it could be hard to "fill in" the ugly white spaces in the background between the black paragraphs, without altering or knowing the inherited margins, and given that there could also be other elements that need color changes such as `ul`, `ol`, `backquote`, etc... so. Javascript it'll have to be.

Comment: Well actually, you can still trick this out too  xD, ill write an example when i get on a pc  (on mobile now)

Comment: Oh, sweet :D I know there will be far less than 100 headings so I'd prefer a CSS solution, if it can work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

While some users have provided some "solutions" that accomplish the request of the original question, the real issue lies in the structure of the HTML. Said another way ... since you are wanting to visually style groupings of content, you should have the content grouped in some sort of parent element (e.g. `div`, `ul`, `article`, etc.) initially. Once the content is setup in this fashion, CSS has a variety of ways to handle such a request that are entirely reasonable unlike most of these suggested "solutions" that rely either on the foreknowledge of how many `h3`s or `p`s you'll have *or* a script to decipher what should already be apparent in your HTML structure.

Most CMSs offer some way to allow pre-defined HTML elements to remain intact, which would allow them to be used.

Fixing the real issue (the HTML structure) should be your focus, instead of painting bad markup with even worse CSS. It may be possible to paint a pile of poop to look like a delicious cheeseburger, but anyone that attempts to consume it will be incredibly disappointed.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the HTML structure--it's perfectly standard. It is *not* normal to wrap a heading and its associated content together in a `div`. Also, changing the HTML could be difficult since the source text is Markdown, not HTML, and the conversion from MD->HTML is done by GitHub, not me (although GH recently switched to Kramdown which allows HTML tags that contain MD, so I guess it's easier now). You are right about one thing - the solutions proposed here don't work very well. It seems Javascript is the way to go.